# How can this value in a switch-statement be uninitialized?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I have this code:

```
int putReferenceItem(Reference reference) {
    switch (reference.type) {
        case CLASS:
            return putStringItem(CONSTANT_Class, reference.name);
        case FIELD:
        case METHOD:
        case INTERFACE_METHOD:
            int itemTag;
            switch (reference.type) {
                case FIELD:
                    itemTag = CONSTANT_Fieldref;
                    break;
                case METHOD:
                    itemTag = CONSTANT_Methodref;
                    break;
                case INTERFACE_METHOD:
                    itemTag = CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref;
                    break;
            }
            return putStringItem(itemTag, reference.owner, reference.name, reference.descriptor);
        case HANDLE:
            return put(CONSTANT_MethodHandle, reference.kind, 0, 0, reference.owner, reference.name, reference.descriptor);
        case TYPE:
            return putStringItem(CONSTANT_MethodType, reference.descriptor);
        default:
            throw new Error("Unreachable code.");
    }
}
```

On the line,

```
return putStringItem(itemTag, reference.owner, reference.name, reference.descriptor);
```

The compiler complains that the value of `itemTag` may not have been initialized. It seems pretty obvious to me that the nested switch-statement will always initialize the value of `itemTag` so I am having a hard time understanding why this error is generated. Is the compiler simply not sophisticated enough to evaluate the nested switch-statement, or is it actually possible for `itemTag` to be uninitialized?

My current solution is to simply add a default case that throws an `Error` as such:

```
            switch (reference.type) {
                case FIELD:
                    itemTag = CONSTANT_Fieldref;
                    break;
                case METHOD:
                    itemTag = CONSTANT_Methodref;
                    break;
                case INTERFACE_METHOD:
                    itemTag = CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Error("Unreachable code.");
            }
```

However, I feel like this is a pretty ugly solution. (**Update**: I just realized that I could replace `case INTERFACE_METHOD:` with `default:` and still get the same behavior without the ugliness. My question still stands though.)

You may have also noticed that I have re-used this solution later on in the code to avoid having to return a value. This switch-statement has a case for each constant defined in `ReferenceType`, so I am not entirely sure how the code could be missing a `return` statement.

```
public enum ReferenceType {

    CLASS,
    FIELD,
    METHOD,
    INTERFACE_METHOD,
    HANDLE,
    TYPE
}
```

Why does the compiler generate these errors?

Comment: Why dont you just put `int itemTag` outside the switch, and then get rid of the nested?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler won't look inside your switch-statements to see if you initialize the variable. If it is isn't initialized within the current scope (e.g. outside the switch statement where you created the variable), you are going to get this error. The purpose of this is to protect you from calling "null" when you call the variable later on in your code.

If you know for a fact that it is always going to be set to the correct value within the switch statement, then it should be safe to initialize the variable with an arbitrary value. Whether or not this is the most graceful solution is up for debate, but it should solve your problem. I think it is better than dealing with errors like you have.

EDIT:

Regarding the second half of the question, I think that creating a variable to return in the correct scope could solve your problem. E.g. If you initialize a variable (again with an arbitrary value) then you can set it with the correct value in the switch statement and then return the variable at the end of the method. That should get rid of the error.

Comment: The error is generated at compile-time so I'm confused about the role of the JVM in this.

Comment: [citation needed] - could you provide some relevant documentation?

Comment: It's the compiler, not the JVM, and it's an error, not a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you have any input regarding the latter portion of my question? (About returning a value.)

Comment: @BenjaminLowry - This is not a scope related problem.  It is actually (fundamentally) about the "definite assignment" rules in the JLS spec, and how they work in the case of a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code in question

```
int itemTag;
switch (reference.type) {
    case FIELD:
        itemTag = CONSTANT_Fieldref;
        break;
    case METHOD:
        itemTag = CONSTANT_Methodref;
        break;
    case INTERFACE_METHOD:
        itemTag = CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref;
        break;
}
```

Clearly `itemTag` is initialized if `reference.type` is one of those three `enum` values.  But what about the other two?  In the code as written, if they were to occur, the `switch` statement would not initialize `itemTag`.

Now you (the programmer) may be able to deduce that those other two cases cannot happen.  But the compiler can't.  In order to make that deduction, the compiler would need a deep understanding of the semantics of your `Reference` class, and how you are using it.  It simply cannot do that.

The solution is to change the above to something like this:

```
int itemTag;
switch (reference.type) {
    case FIELD:
        itemTag = CONSTANT_Fieldref;
        break;
    case METHOD:
        itemTag = CONSTANT_Methodref;
        break;
    case INTERFACE_METHOD:
        itemTag = CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref;
        break;
    default:
        throw AssertionError("impossible reference type");
}
```

The compiler will now be able to deduce that `itemTag` is initialized for all possible ways that you can reach the `return` statement where the variable is used.

---

Incidentally, the following is NOT a valid solution.

```
int itemTag;
switch (reference.type) {
    case FIELD:
        itemTag = CONSTANT_Fieldref;
        break;
    case METHOD:
        itemTag = CONSTANT_Methodref;
        break;
    case INTERFACE_METHOD:
        itemTag = CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref;
        break;
    case CLASS: case HANDLE: case TYPE:
        throw AssertionError("impossible reference type");
}
```

The reason that this is not a solution is that classes in Java can be recompiled in any order.  Suppose that the above code was compiled, and then you changed the `enum` declaration to add a new constant, and recompiled it.  Now *at runtime* the switch statement above no longer covers all possible cases, and that means that `itemTag` *could* be used without being initialized.  OOOPS!

Hence the compiler will complain about the above code, saying that `itemTag` might not always be initialized.

Weird ... and UGLY ... but necessary, for the reasons above.

Comment: I've also realized that replacing `case INTERFACE_METHOD` with `default` also gives the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to me it is not so obvious the value will be initialized.

Look below where I inserted `<here>`. Now imagine when execution is at this point another thread kicks in and changes `reference.type` to `HANDLE` and voilá, you have a value for which you have no branch in your `switch` and the value will be uninitialized.

```
case INTERFACE_METHOD:
    int itemTag;
    // <here>
    switch (reference.type) {
        case FIELD:
            itemTag = CONSTANT_Fieldref;
            break;
        case METHOD:
            itemTag = CONSTANT_Methodref;
            break;
        case INTERFACE_METHOD:
            itemTag = CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref;
            break;
    }
    return putStringItem(itemTag, reference.owner, reference.name, reference.descriptor);
```

Besides that, if you don't want to cover the case that reference.type changes, why do you have an inner switch at all? Wouldn't the code then better be this in the outer switch?

```
case INTERFACE_METHOD:
    return putStringItem(CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref, reference.owner, reference.name, reference.descriptor);
```

Comment: If I define a local variable `ReferenceType type = reference.type;` and use that in the `switch` rather than `reference.type` then the concurrency would not be an issue, yet the error is still generated.

Comment: Well, then you are at the second part of my question. If the variable `type` cannot change, it makes no sense to have the inner `switch` statement. Why the error is generated probably is because the compiler is dumb to a certain limit. Also it doesn't make any sense to add that piece of intelligence, as the whole inner switch is senseless if the value cannot change between the evaluation of the outer and the inner switch, so the inner switch is not needed as described in my answer. So adding intelligence for nonsense is not worth the effort. ;-)